# Why does this query take over 5 seconds to run?

Tags: mysql, datetime, query-optimization

I have a MySQL table with around 2m rows in it. I'm trying to run the below query and each time it's taken over 5 seconds to get results. I have an index on `created_at` column. Below is the `EXPLAIN` output.

Is this expected?

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT
  DATE(created_at) AS grouped_date,
  HOUR(created_at) AS grouped_hour,
  count(*) AS requests
FROM
  `advert_requests`
WHERE
  DATE(created_at) BETWEEN '2022-09-09' AND '2022-09-12'
GROUP BY
  grouped_date,
  grouped_hour
```

[image]

Comment: There are 2.8 million rows that match the `WHERE` condition. Splitting it up into date and hour for the grouping is expensive.

Comment: DATE function won't use an index if there is one on created_at

Comment: @ErgestBasha The explain output says it's using the key.

Comment: Try change `DATE(created_at) BETWEEN '2022-09-09' AND '2022-09-12'` with `created_at BETWEEN '2022-09-08  23:59:59' AND '2022-09-12 23:59:59'` and chek if it would make difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The EXPLAIN shows `type: index` which is an index-scan. That is, it is using the index, but it's iterating over *every* entry in the index, like a table-scan does for rows in the table. This is supported by `rows: 2861816` which tells you the optimizer's estimate of quantity of index entries it will examine (this is a rough number). This is much more expensive than examining only the rows matching the condition, which is the benefit we look for from an index.

So why is this?

When you use any function on an index column in your search like this:

```
WHERE
  DATE(created_at) BETWEEN '2022-09-09' AND '2022-09-12'
```

It spoils the benefit of the index for reducing the number of rows examined.

MySQL's optimizer doesn't have any intelligence about the result of functions, so it can't infer that the order of return values will be in the same order as the index. Therefore it can't use the fact that the index is sorted to narrow down the search. You and I know that this is natural for `DATE(created_at)` to be in the same order as `created_at`, but the query optimizer doesn't know this. There are other functions like `MONTH(created_at)` where the results are definitely *not* in sorted order, and MySQL's optimizer doesn't attempt to know which function's results are reliably sorted.

To fix your query, you can try one of two things:

Use an expression index. This is a new feature in MySQL 8.0:

```
ALTER TABLE `advert_requests` ADD INDEX ((DATE(created_at)))
```

Notice the extra redundant pair of parentheses. These are required when defining an expression index. The index entries are the results of that function or expression, not the original values of the column.

If you then use the same expression in your query, the optimizer recognizes that and uses the index.

```
mysql> explain SELECT   DATE(created_at) AS grouped_date,   HOUR(created_at) AS grouped_hour,   count(*) AS requests FROM   `advert_requests` WHERE   DATE(created_at) BETWEEN '2022-09-09' AND '2022-09-12' GROUP BY   grouped_date,   grouped_hour\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: advert_requests
   partitions: NULL
         type: range          <-- much better than 'index'
possible_keys: functional_index
          key: functional_index
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary
```

If you use MySQL 5.7, you can't use expression indexes directly, but you can use a virtual column and define an index on the virtual column:

```
ALTER TABLE advert_requests
  ADD COLUMN created_at_date DATE AS (DATE(created_at)),
  ADD INDEX (created_at_date);
```

The trick of the optimizer recognizing the expression still works.

If you use a version of MySQL older than 5.7, you should upgrade regardless. MySQL 5.6 and older versions are past their end of life by now, and they are security risks.

The second thing you could do is refactor your query so the `created_at` column is not inside a function.

```
WHERE
  created_at >= '2022-09-09' AND created_at < '2022-09-13'
```

When comparing a datetime to a date value, the date value is implicitly at 00:00:00.000 time. To include every fraction of a second up to 2022-09-12 23:59:59.999, it's simpler to just use `< '2022-09-13'`.

The EXPLAIN of this shows that it uses the existing index on `created_at`.

```
mysql> explain SELECT   DATE(created_at) AS grouped_date,   HOUR(created_at) AS grouped_hour,   count(*) AS requests FROM   `advert_requests` WHERE   created_at >= '2022-09-09' AND created_at < '2022-09-13' GROUP BY   grouped_date,   grouped_hour\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: advert_requests
   partitions: NULL
         type: range        <-- not 'index'
possible_keys: created_at
          key: created_at
      key_len: 6
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index condition; Using temporary
```

This solution works on older versions of MySQL as well as 5.7 and 8.0.

Comment: Bill, what an absolutely fantastic answer. Thank you so much for taking the time and going into so much detail.

I added `ALTER TABLE advert_requests ADD INDEX ((DATE(created_at)))` to the table and the same query is now taking 350ms instead of over 4 seconds.

My `EXPLAIN` shows more or less exactly the same as your example.

this is fascinating, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the `EXPLAIN` correctly, it's able to use the index to implement the `WHERE` filtering. But this is returning 2.8 million rows, which then have to be grouped by date and hour, and this is a slow process.

You may be able to improve it by creating virtual columns for the date and hour, and index these as well.

```
ALTER TABLE advert_requests
ADD COLUMN created_date DATE AS (DATE(created_at)), ADD column created_hour INT AS (HOUR(created_at)), ADD INDEX (created_date, created_hour);
```

Comment: It's missing data type and I think the definition for the virtual column should be enclosed with a pair of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Use `explain analysis` and check whether it is `Index range scan` or not.  if not follow this link:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html
(Note that sometimes full table scan can be better if most of the timestamps in the table belong to the selected date range. As I know in such case optimization is not trivial)

Comment: It will have better performance, but it will only match values of `created_at` that happen to be at 00:00:00 time. So it will fail to include all the other entries that occurred at different times of day.

Comment: agree with you.